# How to get view in expandable list view in my case do not show expandable list it shows Blank

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am working on expandablelistview, but I don't able to get expandable listView , please help me to get fault in my code thanks in advance

**CodeMainActicity.java**

```
 public class CodeMainActicity extends Activity {
    private ExpandListAdapter ExpAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> ExpListItems;
    private ExpandableListView ExpandList;
    public String[] groups = null;
    public String[][] headers = null;
    DisplayMetrics metrics;
    int width;

    public int GetDipsFromPixel(float paramFloat) {
        return (int) (0.5F + paramFloat
                * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }

    public ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> SetStandardGroups() {
        ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> localArrayList1 = new ArrayList<ExpandListGroup>();
        int i = 0;
        if (i >= groups.length) {
            return localArrayList1;
        }
        ExpandListGroup localExpandListGroup = new ExpandListGroup();
        localExpandListGroup.setName(groups[i]);
        ArrayList<ExpandListChild> localArrayList2 = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            while (headers[i][j] == null) {
                localExpandListGroup.setItems(localArrayList2);
                localArrayList1.add(localExpandListGroup);
                i++;
                break;
            }
            ExpandListChild localExpandListChild = new ExpandListChild();
            localExpandListChild.setName(headers[i][j]);
            localExpandListChild.setTag(null);
            localArrayList2.add(localExpandListChild);

        }
        return localArrayList1;

    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
        groups = new String[11];
        headers = ((String[][]) Array.newInstance(String.class, new int[] { 14,
                10 }));
        groups[0] = "Data Types";
        groups[1] = "Date Time";
        groups[2] = "Regular Expressions";
        groups[3] = "Class";
        groups[4] = "Collections";
        groups[5] = "Generics";
        groups[6] = "Reflection";
        groups[7] = "Security";
        groups[8] = "Design Patterns";
        groups[9] = "Thread";
        groups[10] = "File Stream";
        headers[0][0] = "Boxing and Unboxing";
        headers[0][1] = "Complex Type";
        headers[0][2] = "Enum";
        headers[0][3] = "Tuple type";
        headers[0][4] = "Hex to Int";
        headers[0][5] = "Nullable Integer";
        headers[0][6] = "Custom ToString()";
        headers[0][7] = "Checked() and Unchecked()";
        headers[0][8] = "Overflow";
        headers[0][9] = "Char  methods";
        headers[1][0] = "Get between Days";
        headers[1][1] = "Add one week to current date";
        headers[1][2] = "DateTime Compare";
        headers[2][0] = "Email Validation";
        headers[2][1] = "URL validation";
        headers[2][2] = "Zipcode validation";
        headers[3][0] = "Access modifiers";
        headers[3][1] = "Inheritance";
        headers[3][2] = "Interface";
        headers[3][3] = "Method Overloading";
        headers[3][4] = "Overriding";
        headers[3][5] = "Abstract class";
        headers[4][0] = "Array List";
        headers[4][1] = "Hash Table";
        headers[4][2] = "Dictionary";
        headers[5][0] = "Simple Generic hierarchy";
        headers[5][1] = "Generic IEnumerable";
        headers[5][2] = "Generic Collection class";
        headers[6][0] = "AppDomain Setup";
        headers[6][1] = "Type.GetMethods";
        headers[6][2] = "Assembly Version Information";
        headers[7][0] = "MD5 encode";
        headers[7][1] = "File Checksum";
        headers[7][2] = "Password Encryption";
        headers[8][0] = "Facade Pattern";
        headers[8][1] = "Factory Pattern";
        headers[8][2] = "Observer Pattern";
        headers[8][3] = "Singleton Pattern";
        headers[8][4] = "Adapter Pattern";
        headers[9][0] = "Creating Thread";
        headers[9][1] = "Asynchronous Calls";
        headers[9][2] = "Mutex";
        headers[10][0] = "Display File contents";
        headers[10][1] = "Write to a file";
        headers[10][2] = "Append to File";
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        requestWindowFeature(1);
        setContentView(R.layout.codemainscreen);
        Button localButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnhome);
        ExpandList = ((ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.ExpList));
        ExpListItems = SetStandardGroups();
        ExpAdapter = new ExpandListAdapter(this, ExpListItems);
        metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        width = metrics.widthPixels;
        ExpandList.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetDipsFromPixel(50.0F), width
                - GetDipsFromPixel(10.0F));
        ExpandList.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);
        ExpandList
                .setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
                    public boolean onChildClick(
                            ExpandableListView paramAnonymousExpandableListView,
                            View paramAnonymousView, int paramAnonymousInt1,
                            int paramAnonymousInt2, long paramAnonymousLong) {
                        Bundle localBundle = new Bundle();
                        localBundle.putString("group",
                                Integer.toString(paramAnonymousInt1));
                        localBundle.putString("item",
                                Integer.toString(paramAnonymousInt2));
                        Intent localIntent = new Intent(CodeMainActicity.this
                                .getApplicationContext(),
                                CodeDisplayAcitvity.class);
                        localIntent.putExtras(localBundle);
                        CodeMainActicity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
        localButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView) {
                Intent localIntent = new Intent(CodeMainActicity.this
                        .getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                CodeMainActicity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**ExpandListAdapter:**

```
     public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> groups;

    public ExpandListAdapter(Context paramContext,
            ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> paramArrayList) {
        this.context = paramContext;
        this.groups = paramArrayList;
    }

    public void addItem(ExpandListChild paramExpandListChild,
            ExpandListGroup paramExpandListGroup) {
        if (!this.groups.contains(paramExpandListGroup))
            this.groups.add(paramExpandListGroup);
        int i = this.groups.indexOf(paramExpandListGroup);
        ArrayList<ExpandListChild> localArrayList = ((ExpandListGroup) this.groups
                .get(i)).getItems();
        localArrayList.add(paramExpandListChild);
        ((ExpandListGroup) this.groups.get(i)).setItems(localArrayList);
    }

    public Object getChild(int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
        return ((ExpandListGroup) this.groups.get(paramInt1)).getItems().get(
                paramInt2);
    }

    public long getChildId(int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
        return paramInt2;
    }

    public View getChildView(int paramInt1, int paramInt2,
            boolean paramBoolean, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
        ExpandListChild localExpandListChild = (ExpandListChild) getChild(
                paramInt1, paramInt2);
        if (paramView == null)
            paramView = ((LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService("layout_inflater")).inflate(
                    R.layout.expandlist_child_item, null);
        TextView localTextView = (TextView) paramView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvChild);
        localTextView.setText(localExpandListChild.getName().toString());
        localTextView.setTag(localExpandListChild.getTag());
        return paramView;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int paramInt) {
        return ((ExpandListGroup) this.groups.get(paramInt)).getItems().size();
    }

    public Object getGroup(int paramInt) {
        return this.groups.get(paramInt);
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.groups.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int paramInt) {
        return paramInt;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int paramInt, boolean paramBoolean,
            View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
        ExpandListGroup localExpandListGroup = (ExpandListGroup) getGroup(paramInt);
        if (paramView == null) {
            paramView = ((LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService("layout_inflater")).inflate(
                    R.layout.expandlist_group_item, null);
        }
        ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.btngo))
                .setText(localExpandListGroup.getName());
        return paramView;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**ExpandListChild:**

```
    public class ExpandListChild {
    private String Name;
    private String Tag;

    public String getName() {
        return this.Name;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return this.Tag;
    }

    public void setName(String paramString) {
        this.Name = paramString;
    }

    public void setTag(String paramString) {
        this.Tag = paramString;
    }
}
```

**ExpandListGroup:**

```
     public class ExpandListGroup {
    private ArrayList<ExpandListChild> Items;
    private String Name;

    public ArrayList<ExpandListChild> getItems() {
        return this.Items;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.Name;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<ExpandListChild> paramArrayList) {
        this.Items = paramArrayList;
    }

    public void setName(String paramString) {
        this.Name = paramString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you googled and tried any tutorial of `Expandable Listview` ?

Comment: yes i have tried, but i unable to find problem in my code

Comment: Related: [Sample Code for ExpandableListView DateTime as Header](https://experiments-on-android.blogspot.com/b/post-preview?token=HAW4l0sBAAA.w4NYfvVaiPNkErNQjoeBnw.qVQnPkdBSCnak8XvBRgjWA&postId=1207135633310116375&type=POST#!/2015/02/group-by-month-and-display-result-in.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SetStandardGroups() - You are creating only one instance of ExpandListGroup and adding items to that group. You are not adding second group items to the result ArrayList (localArrayList1). Try with following code...

```
public ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> SetStandardGroups() 
{
    ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> resExpList = new ArrayList<ExpandListGroup>();

    if(groups != null && groups.length > 0)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<groups.length; i++)
        {
            ExpandListGroup expListGroup = new ExpandListGroup();
            expListGroup.setName(groups[i]);
            Log.e("ExpList", "Group "+i+" Name="+groups[i]);

            ArrayList<ExpandListChild> expListItems = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();
            for(int j=0; j<headers[i].length; j++)
            {
                ExpandListChild item = new ExpandListChild();
                item.setName(headers[i][j]);
                Log.e("ExpList", "Item "+j+" ="+headers[i][j]);

                item.setTag(null);
                expListItems.add(item);
            }
            expListGroup.setItems(expListItems);
            Log.e("ExpList", "Group "+i+" items size="+expListGroup.size());

            resExpList.add(expListGroup);
        }
    }

    Log.e("ExpList", "Total groups size="+resExpList.size());
    return resExpList;
}
```

Comment: nul pointer exception in ExpandListAdapter.java at ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.btngo)).setText(localExpandListGroup.getName());

Comment: 04-09 05:44:30.057: E/AndroidRuntime(255): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-09 05:44:30.124: E/AndroidRuntime(255): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-09 05:44:30.124: E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at com.example.apktesting.ExpandListAdapter.getGroupView(ExpandListAdapter.java:81)

Comment: I inserted Logs... try once, filter the logcat with 'ExpList' tag. send the logcat..

Comment: i hcanged it into expListItems.size()

Comment: @kamal I don't think you fully understand how this site works, or the bounties.